# Intellij doesn't recognize the multi module gradle with kotlin dsl java project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Hi have gradle multi module java project using kotlin dsl.

My root project `build.gradle.kts` is -

```
    allprojects {
       group = "org.example"
       version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    }

    subprojects {
        apply(plugin = "java")
        apply(plugin = "application")

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
        }

        configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }

        dependencies {
            val implementation by configurations
            val testImplementation by configurations
            implementation("org.apache.kafka", "kafka-streams", "2.7.0")
            testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-api", "5.7.1")
        }
    }
```

My root module `settings.gradle.kts` contents -

```
rootProject.name = "Mastering-Kafka-Streams-Ksqldb"
include("getting-started")
```

The contents of `getting-started` subproject `build.gradle.kts` -

```
tasks.register<JavaExec>("runDSL") {
  main = "com.example.DSLExample"
  classpath ( sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath)
}


tasks.register<JavaExec> ("runProcessorAPI") {
  main = "com.example.ProcessorApiExample"
  classpath ( sourceSets.main.get().runtimeClasspath)
}
```

The contents of `getting-started` subproject `settings.gradle.kts` -

```
rootProject.name = "getting-started"
```

I've a java file `DSLExample.java` in directory `getting-started/src/main/java/com/example/DSLExample.java`

when I execute tasks like grade `getting-started:compileJava` or `getting-started:runDSL` or `getting-started: runProcessorAPI` it is working fine.

But Intellij is not recognizing dependencies and IDE has lot of compilation errors.

[image: Gradle kotlin DSL multi module java project compilation errors]

The project is on [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/Mastering-Kafka-Streams-Ksqldb). How can I fix the IDE issues?

Note:

I'm using Intellij Idea 2020.3.2 Utimate version.

Gradle version is -

```
$gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.8.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-02-05 12:53:00 UTC
Revision:     b9bd4a5c6026ac52f690eaf2829ee26563cad426

Kotlin:       1.4.20
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64
```

I've created an issue for idea as well. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-262967

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Were there any errors when you loaded the Gradle project in IDE?

Comment: did the clone project and import it in idea?